# hp desktjet 1000 j110 network needs authentication

Tags: printing, authentication

I have a DesktopJet 1000 j110 printer that is detected and shared among the network i have setup..the problem I'm running into is it WANTS authentication to print..I never setup a password, or a username. I have samba installed allowing "anyone" to use the printer..but it's the same results...this is so annoying.

Answer (score 2):

I answered my own question by going to the Printing tab
in the system settings menu. Then I went to settings and checked the following:

- Show printers shared by other systems;
- Published shared printers connected to this system;
- Allow printing from the internet;
- Allow remote administration;
- Allow users to cancel any job.